# Create multiple records for the same company

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-analysis, data-warehouse

I do have some duplications in my company_clients table. Some of them due to poor tool usage and some of them because the company is located in more than one country and we assign different group for each, so I need to keep them as 2 companies.

I'm struggling to write the logic to a query and I'm still questioning the logic.

The way I'll differentiate the two cases is as follows:
1- if the company record is in the same location or one of the duplication is null because it wasn't filled = I'll consider this as same company and I should have only one record for it
2- if the company is duplicated but with different location then they should be separated.

I used row_number(), partition by the country but its not working

[image]

Comment: Could you add examples of your start data and the desired output?

Comment: Source table definitions, sample data for them and the required result (formatted as tables) - plus the SQL you've managed to write so far (formatted as code)

Comment: @ollimandoliini attached a photo for the current and desired output

Comment: Hi - please don't link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text. People often want to try out solutions using your data/SQL and it you provide information as pictures then it can't be copied and it makes it much less likely people will help you

Comment: Hi @NickW - I tried to edit my question and create a table but for some reason the option wasn't there so I had to snippet and attach it as a photo

Comment: Table markup: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function and conditional logic.

Here's an example SQL query that you can use:

```
WITH RankedCompanies AS (
  SELECT
  company_id,
  company_name,
  location,
  country,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY company_name, COALESCE(location, '')         ORDER BY company_id) AS RowNum

FROM
company_clients
)
DELETE FROM RankedCompanies
WHERE RowNum > 1;
```

Comment: Just noting that this answer when using a DELETE FROM a CTE that it will make an attempt to actually DELETE records from the database.  Be aware that using a DELETE/UPDATE on a CTE is not at all similar to DELETing or UPDATing a Temp table.